# Create slug using django-uuslug

Tags: django, unicode, slug

I'm trying to create slugs with [django-uuslug](https://github.com/un33k/django-uuslug) in blog app with no success. What i'm doing wrong? 
My code as follows:

```
class Post(models.Model):
image   = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/', blank=True, null=True)
title  = models.CharField(max_length=120)
slug = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
content  = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

@property
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title 

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = uuslug(self.title, instance=self, max_length=200)
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What is the problem?
Did you get an error?

Comment: I don't get an error, but slugs do not seem to be created.

Comment: You do not specify any default value for slug, and it is not nullable. If you successfully  save you model it possible only if you `uuslug` function returns empty string `""`